# Bugs in user section

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I'm assuming there has been an update because the user section now has some bugs in it:

[image]

However when you switch to tracking your progress - it goes back to what it originally was. The following aren't there when you track progress, but are there when you track tag badges:

1. The cog for choosing to track progress or tag badges is too high up and this is creating too much space in the first box.
2. There seems to be lots of extra space at the bottom of the second box
3. The 'people reached' is not in line (this sees to be an update) but there is a load of space beneath it

This also happens on my profile on meta, though less severely.

Also: whenever you reload the boxes start of really elongated before squashing back into the shapes in the picture.

This is on chrome - windows 10

Comment: this isn't a bug. It's an update. (pretty sure)

Comment: @ItamarG3 seems pretty pointless - there is just a ton of extra space now. I doubt that was intended?

Comment: You'll notice color and layout changes in the badges screen, and the progress bars everywhere in the user page are redesigned in their color (which is now a gradient color)

Comment: @ItamarG3 I don't think this is an update - not everyone is seeing the same as me.

Comment: I am, and so are many, many people I've asked in the [cseducators.se] chat.

Comment: @ItamarG3 hmmm strange. Everyone I've asked so far in The Sphinx's Lair isn't seeing the same. Perhaps there was a bug with the update then, and it didn't go to everyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the items that you have listed are [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The full list of updated items can be found in [this post on Meta.SO.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351378/2640230)

Addressing the items you have mentioned…

> 1. The cog for choosing to track progress or tag badges is too high up and this is creating too much space in the first box.

This menu toggle is now placed above the progress bars instead of to the right as previously positioned.

> 2. There seems to be lots of extra space at the bottom of the second box

Yes, this is mainly because the highlight boxes all have uniform height now. When there's less content, the space decreases. When there's more content, it grows. I explored having the second row of content with the Badges box align more to the bottom, but it left a lot of space in the middle. This was the best layout of the two.

> 3. The 'people reached' is not in line (this sees to be an update) but there is a load of space beneath it

Since the Impact box is slightly smaller width-wise and we have a little more room vertically, this created some trapped white-space. Also the "people reached" label font-size was increased to 12px. While this makes it easier to read than before, it also causes the line to wrap. [A community request on Meta.SO asked for the trapped white space to be reduced.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351380/the-new-theme-has-a-lot-of-space-between-impact-and-bottom-parts) Pushing this label underneath the number allowed us to fill this space slightly and keep the label from breaking to two lines.

> Also: whenever you reload the boxes start of really elongated before squashing back into the shapes in the picture.

I think this is a bug related to the JS. I'll work with the team to figure out what's happening here exactly.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure I am a massive fan of most of these updates but at least its not a bug.